# Bubble.io API Connector with Lambda + AWS Rekognition Problem

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-rekognition, bubble.io

Hi I was trying to use AWS Rekognition -> Lambda -> AWS API -> Bubble.io
I want to pass a image base64 code to process the image recognition.

Here is the lambda code:

```
import json
import boto3
import base64


def lambda_handler(event, context):

    def detect_labels():

        # 1. create a client object, to connect to rekognition
        client=boto3.client('rekognition')


        image = base64.b64decode(event['face'])

        # 4. call Rekognition, store result in 'response'
        response = client.detect_labels(
                Image={
                    'Bytes': image
                    },
                MaxLabels=20,
                )


        #6. Return response from function
        return response


    # Call detect_labels
    response = detect_labels()

    # Return results to API gateway
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(response)
        }
```

and if I test it within the lambda test with config:

```
{
  "face": "<imgbase64codehere>"
}
```

It works fine and return success message.
However I set the same thing in Bubble.io
[Setting img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kgmrh.png). It wont work.

I check the Cloudwatch, the error is:

```
[ERROR] KeyError: 'face'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 30, in lambda_handler
    response = detect_labels()
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 14, in detect_labels
    image = base64.b64decode(event['face'])
[ERROR] KeyError: 'face' Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 30, in lambda_handler     response = detect_labels()   File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 14, in detect_labels     image = base64.b64decode(event['face'])
```

I am sure there is not connection problem (if I dont use JSON it works fine)
So what do I do wrong in the setting?
Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your test you are sending an input of just a JSON request with face.

It looks like the implementation you've setup uses Amazon API Gateway. If you are doing that your Lambda function might receive the event in a different format depending on how you've implemented the API Gateway integration.

The [Lambda developer guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway.html) has an example of the JSON format. You will probably want to access the body attribute.